# PreparedStatement setObject method passing parameter as String or Object

Tags: java, jdbc, collections

I trying to set PreparedStatements values using it's `setObject(Object o)` method Like this:

```
 List<String> whereValues = new ArrayList<>();
 whereValues.add("m");
 PreparedStatement ps = null;
 try {
     ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
     int i = 1;

     for (String object : whereValues){
         ps.setObject(i, object);
         i++;
     }
 } catch (SQLException ex) {
     System.out.println(ex);
 }
```

When executed this works fine and it does return me a row but when the same code is changed like this (it's using a declared type of `Object` for the parameter rather than `String`) **it returns nothing**:

```
 List whereValues = new ArrayList();  //Now list can accept anything and returns an object when used get()
 whereValues.add("m");
 PreparedStatement ps = null;
 try {
     ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
     int i = 1;

     for (Object object : whereValues){
         ps.setObject(i, object);
         i++;
     }
 } catch (SQLException ex) {
     System.out.println(ex);
 }
```

When this executes it returns nothing nor throws any exceptions. Can somebody explain why this is happening?

Comment: There should be no difference in the result of that code. `setObject` doesn't care about the declared type of the second parameter. Are you sure you didn't change something else too? --- FYI: Using *raw* classes is a bad idea. Use `List<Object> whereVaues = new ArrayList<>()` if you want mixed values. --- Also, use try-with-resources: `try (PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {`

Comment: Well list<Object> l is same as list l

Comment: I am really sorry but PreparedStaement thing u suggested that does not make any difference either .ThankYou

Comment: `List<Object>` is *not* the same as `List`. The first is a *generic* list of objects of type `Object` or a subtype. The second is a *raw* list. *generic* lists and *raw* lists are not the same.

Comment: Anyway, as I already stated, changing `whereValues` from `List<String>` to `List` makes no difference to the `ps.setObject(i, object)` statement, so the two blocks of code will do the same thing. If you get different results when you actually `execute()` the statement (code you didn't show), then there is some other difference causing that.

Comment: Well ThankYou for the answer :D